# Copy value of url input from form1 to action url form2

Tags: jquery

```
<form id="1" method="post">
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" />

<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>

<form id="2" action="http://www.domain1.com/form1.php?url=url from form1 input field" method="post"></form>
```

I tried a lot, but am not able to figure it out. ((jQuery): append, onblur etc etc)

When I type an URL in form1, I would like the url to be copied to the form2 action, after ?url=
Additional the url should only contain www no http://
Than press 1 submit button and post both forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
      <form id="frmOne" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="www.url.com">
        <input name="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
    <form id="frmTwo"></form>
    <div id="txtMessage"></div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                  <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
                    <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAccount">Access your account</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

<script>

    //Cache variables
    var $frmOne = $('#frmOne'),
        $frmTwo = $('#frmTwo'),
        $txtMessage = $('#txtMessage'),
        frmTwoAction = 'http://www.domain1.com/form1.php?url=',
        $myModal     = $('#myModal');

    //Form 1 sumbit event
    $frmOne.on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var strUrl = $frmOne.find('#url').val();

        //validation
        if (strUrl === ''){
            $txtMessage.html('<b>Missing Information: </b> Please enter a URL.');
        } else if (strUrl.substring(0, 7) === 'http://') {
            //Clear field
            $frmOne.find('#url').val('');
            $txtMessage.html('<b>http://</b> is not supported!');
        } else if (strUrl.substring(0, 4) !== 'www.') {
            //Clear field
            $frmOne.find('#url').val('');
            $txtMessage.html('<b>Invalid URL</b> Please enter a valid URL!');
        } else {


            //You can update these here if you want
            $myModal.find('.modal-title').text('Adding new Modal Title from jQuery');
            //$myModal.find('.modal-body p').text('Adding new Modal body from jQuery');

            //Open modal
            $myModal.modal('show');

            //Setup click event on button in modal
            $('#btnAccount').on('click', function(e){            
                //goto page location
                document.location = 'http://www.ACCOUNT-URL.com';
            });

            //set form action and submit form
            //$frmTwo.attr('action', frmTwoAction + strUrl).submit();

            //return true; // let form one submit now!
        }
        return false;

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add a modal to it? My #frmTwo has a progress bar. This way i could show it.

Comment: Easy enough - are you using bootstrap? You have a link or more code to share so I can see what you're doing?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap for my website. #frmTwo is showing the progress bar. #frmOne  has the url field but also 5 more fields that are required (trying to get it to work, looking at your solution) But I am not that great with jQuery :-) What part of the code do you need to see?

Comment: Besides the progressbar, what is already working. The modal should have one button, goto your account. closing button is not needed. If if it's there it should also goto your account. Goto your account will be a link / url. that's basically all.

Comment: OK @Gfive, I updated the example to include a bootstrap modal - let me know if this is what you had in mind. Also, I setup a quick fiddle to work through the example:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/sbritton/Rb9uR/1/)

Comment: Nice, thanks!!. I am going to play with it. This modal will show my #frmTwo right? When press submit, doing it's magic and shows a modal that shows #frmTwo?

Comment: Actually, I moved the 2nd form submission event inside of the btnAccount click event, so that should be what you're looking for.

Comment: An nice. Let me play with it. Could I contact/hire you if I need to?

Comment: Absolutely. If you have any other questions, just post a message here and I'll respond.

Comment: I have been playing with your code. But could you help me with the following. All is going well with the 2 forms. but when i click on submit the modal will not display my #frmTwo form. My second form has a progress bar. I would like to load form 2 in the modal and show the progress bar to the user. Is this possible?

Comment: I am trying this code now, but still it opens a new screen instead of modal.  //Setup click event on button in modal
        $('#btnAccount').on('click', function(e){  
e.preventDefault();          
            //set form action and submit form
              //var urltest = $frmTwo.attr('action', frmTwoAction + strUrl).submit();

            var url = $frmTwo.attr('action', frmTwoAction + strUrl).submit();
$(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
        });

Comment: OK, I added the progress bar inside of the model - the code has been updated above as well as the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbritton/Rb9uR/6/)

Comment: As for the model not opening, make sure you have the bootstrap files includes on your page (you'll need the CSS and JS include files).

Comment: Thanks. But what I try to do. My form 2 shows a progress bar when called after submit. This is done in a new window. What I want is to show that new window of my form 2 in the modal. That's why I used iframe in the modal.

Comment: Or in other words $('#btnAccount').on('click', function(e){ submits $frmTwo.attr('action', frmTwoAction + strUrl) into iframe in the modal

Comment: Solved it. Added an iframe and set form target to iframe. Now it does what I needed it to do. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use two forms but two divs.

```
$("#submit").on('click',function(){
    $("#2").attr("action",$("#url").val());
});
```

Check out the JSFIDDLE

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GT2fh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#1').find('#url').bind('keyup',function(){
 var inputValue = $(this).val();
 $('#2').attr('action','http://www.domain1.com/form1.php?url='+inputValue);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rbtaw/gz46c/

Answer (score -1):

```
myVar = $("#id").val();
$("#2").attr("action", myVar);
```

Should work, haven't tested it though.